# MySql error syntax in trigger

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

I have a syntax problem in a MySQL trigger, I didn't find the issue.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `after_insert_product` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `ps_product_lang` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.id_shop =1 AND NEW.id_lang = 1) 
THEN 
    DECLARE a TEXT; 
    DECLARE b TEXT; 
    DECLARE c TEXT; 
    SET a = '<p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size: large;"> <span class="mcePageBreak">'; 
    SET b = CONCAT(a,NEW.name); 
    SET c = '</span> </span> </p>'; 
    SET NEW.description = concat(b,c); 
END IF; 
END
```

MySQL says:

> 1064 - Synthax error near 'DECLARE a TEXT; DECLARE b TEXT - lign 4

I just typed from `BEGIN` to `END`, declaration is generated by phpMyAdmin, I'm on the panel. It works without the `IF` condition.

Comment: declare at the top of your trigger

Comment: You need to describe what's wrong, e.g. what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP):*

I have to declare variable out of the `if` structure, it works now.